URL Protocol to Open URL in Specific Browser
I have tried to set a URL protocol to open a URL in a specific browser. Trying to replicate the way microsoft-edge: works.
I have viv-window as below. It opens the program correctly but doesn't carry over the URL. Glad of any help.
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
\viv-window
(Default) = URL:viv-window
URL Protocol = ""
\shell
\open
\command
(Default) = "C:\Users\Rick Donald\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe" "%1"
Thanks :)

Why the Java tag?

Sorry, that was my mistake.  Updated now. Thanks @aled
